# Strange error while starting threads inside django application

Tags: python, django, multithreading, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to do a simple network job (ping) from django process. Django is deployed via apache's mod_wsgi. But code works only during first run, returning the following error on subsequent runs.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/propingui/ping/views.py" in ping
  32.             p = Pool(len(fls))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py" in __init__
  674.         Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py" in __init__
  134.         self._repopulate_pool()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py" in _repopulate_pool
  197.             w.start()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py" in start
  73.         self._parent._children[self] = None

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: '_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_children'
```

The code is below:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

...

def _ping((host, firing_location)):
    pinger = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:" + firing_location)
    return pinger.ping(host)

def ping(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            host = form.cleaned_data['host']
            fls = ['g1','a1']
            p = Pool(len(fls))
            noanswer = False
            try: 
                jobs = p.map(_ping, zip([host]*len(fls), fls) )
            except:
                jobs = []
            ...
            return ...
```

I've tried to google the error but found nothing and I do not understand the exact source of the problem. The interesting thing is that if I change ThreadPool to multiprocessing Pool everything works just fine. I think this is somehow caused by problems with spawning threads inside django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use threading, I had the same problem, eventually gave up and used threading module instead of `ThreadPool` and now everything works just fine, so I think the problem must be with `ThreadPool` not Python threads at all.

You can implement your own `ThreadPool` or reuse what others done (like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/) or [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/203871-a-generic-programming-thread-pool/))

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely a [known Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10015) which occurs when using ThreadPool from within a threading.Thread.

There is `no good solution` for this issue, just workarounds like calling the following in the thread you want to use ThreadPool:

```
if not hasattr(threading.current_thread(), "_children"):
    threading.current_thread()._children = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
```

Comment: I don't understand this workaround. Could you please point me to the more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of mod_wsgi. It's not a good idea to spawn thread or forks inside a wsgi application because it can interfere with how the web server spawns workers for the app.

Maybe you can create a pyro service which will dispatch your pings to all server...

Comment: The ping was a simplest example which I used to test workability of the whole thing, actually I need much more complex interaction. Your idea of moving the whole thing to another pyro service is a good one, but is there an other way? May be I can use another webserver like charrypy or something? Because I will need to manage that pyro service so it could scale and running one instance of it won't be enough.

Comment: If you disable the creation of multiple worker, it should work (you can get more informations [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading)). But it's still a bad idea (especially for performances).

Comment: Ok, so I will definitely move logic to the another pyro service but how should I scale it? Should start several services and load-balance them manually?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used pyro and I can't recommend you the best way to make it scale. Maybe you can open a new question with more details on your pyro service to get advices...

Comment: It may be arising because of mod_wsgi being used, but it could actually be due to a bug in multiprocessing module. A dummy thread instance is created by Python when an external thread, ie., created outside of Python, is used. Seems multiprocessing module may be breaking when such threads exist. This isn't going to be specific to mod_wsgi, but anything that creates threads at C level which call back into Python.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton How should I possible diagnose it and fix it or workaround this problem?

Comment: If you can get it down to a self contained example in one file that I can look at that would help. Get that together and send a post to mod_wsgi mailing list and can look at it there. SO isn't good for back and forth debugging.